# HikariCP - Play Framework 1.2.7 JMX MBean Monitoring

Tags: playframework, frameworks, jmx, playframework-1.x, hikaricp

I'm using HikariCP-java6-2.2.5 on Play Framework 1.2.7

I'd like to register JMX MBean in order to monitor my pool performance but neither 
setting registerMbeans=true on datasource config file nor 
dataSource.setRegisterMbeans(true) doesn't work on Play Framework.

When I list my active MBeans there seems no com.zaxxer.hikari:type=Pool (myPool) entry. I couln't see it on VisualVM MBean plugin too so I supose that HikariCP cannot register its MBean to Play Framework 1.2.7 environment.

Is there another trick for Play Framework in order to register MBeans?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the pool name cannot contain " character in order to register MBean.

application log has:
javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character '"' in value part of property

I changed my configuration:
poolName="MyPool"

to

poolName=MyPool

and it registered correctly. Now I see the values on MBean plugin installed VisualVM.